# Input Mismatch Exception with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a assignment and try to make a program which the text file will be read in java using Scanner.
However,when i try to input some data it displays Input mismatch exception.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Schedule
    {   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner sc = null;
        try 
        {

            sc = new Scanner (new FileReader("E:\\Documents\\Java\\Hackathon2016\\Sample_Folder\\Monday.txt"));
        System.out.println("Enter Subject Code");
            subject = input.next ();
            while (sc.hasNext())
            {
                int time = sc.next ();
                 subjects = sc.next ();
                 String prof = sc.next ();
                 room = sc.nextInt ();

                if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase (subjects))
                {
                    System.out.print ("Your Schedule is at "+time+subject+prof+room);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.getMessage ();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of txt file:

```
TIME SUBJECT Professor Room
07:00am-09:30am Physics1A Ma'am_Mina CON416
10:00am-11:30am MATH21 Sir_Andrew TBA_Anscie
 11:30am-1:00pm SOSC3A Ma'am_Filart TBA_CON
01:00pm-4:00pm CCTN 50 Sir_Jake DCEE_101
```

It keeps saying input mismatch exception
can someone give help?
thanks

Comment: Could you please show the actual error message?

Comment: On first look (besides "hackathon" of course) the room entries don't seem to be ints, while you are trying to scan them as sc.nextInt ();

Comment: This code does not even compile, not only because a lot of variables are not even defined. For example `int time = sc.next ();` will not compile because [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) returns `String` and you attempt to assigne it to an `int` variable. Also in oder to get help as quickly as possible please post the correct error message(s) exactly as you see them (copy/paste).

Comment: The exception is thrown by `Scanner`, not by `FileReader`, as a moment's inspection of the stack trace will tell you. Be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should be like this

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner sc = null;
    try 
    {

        sc = new Scanner (new FileReader("E:\\Documents\\Java\\Hackathon2016\\Sample_Folder\\Monday.txt"));
        System.out.println("Enter Subject Code");
        String subject = input.next();
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            String time = sc.next();
            String subjects = sc.next();
            String prof = sc.next();
            String room = sc.next();

            if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase (subjects))
            {
                System.out.print ("Your Schedule is at "+time+subject+prof+room);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.getMessage ();
    }    
}
```

and for the data line number 4
01:00pm-4:00pm CCTN 50 Sir_Jake DCEE_101
I think it should be 
01:00pm-4:00pm CCTN50 Sir_Jake DCEE_101